# Buttons not utilizing code within them?

Tags: swift, button

I have 2 buttons that change the colors of 6 buttons on the next ViewController. Here is the code I'm using:

```
@IBAction func pHTargetButton(sender: UIButton) {

    chemistryButton0?.setTitle("6.2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton1?.setTitle("6.8", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton2?.setTitle("7.2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton3?.setTitle("7.8", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton4?.setTitle("8.4", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton5?.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    chemistryButton0?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 212, green: 142, blue: 69)
    chemistryButton1?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 209, green: 122, blue: 31)
    chemistryButton2?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 224, green:  80, blue:  9)
    chemistryButton3?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 194, green:  74, blue: 58)
    chemistryButton4?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 208, green:  48, blue: 75)
    chemistryButton5?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255)
    chemistryButton5?.alpha = 0.0

}

@IBAction func ammoniaTargetButton(sender: UIButton) {

    chemistryButton0?.setTitle("0.00", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton1?.setTitle("0.25", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton2?.setTitle("0.50", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton3?.setTitle("1.00", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton4?.setTitle("3.00", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    chemistryButton5?.setTitle("6.00", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    chemistryButton0?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 244, green: 235, blue: 130)
    chemistryButton1?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 233, green: 233, blue: 156)
    chemistryButton2?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 223, green: 238, blue: 141)
    chemistryButton3?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 221, green: 236, blue: 210)
    chemistryButton4?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 202, green: 227, blue: 191)
    chemistryButton5?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 202, green: 216, blue: 173)
    chemistryButton5?.alpha = 1.0

}
```

When I click the first button, nothing happens except the transfer from one ViewControler to the next. The same thing happens with my other second button. I am wondering if I am simply missing something in my code or if I need to connect the buttons on the second ViewController a certain way.

Any input or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: uhh.. the next VC is not even show yet, how can it able to change the color of button for next view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit components which are defined in another controller, you should inform **this** controller to edit its buttons instead of trying to edit them from where you are, there is several way to do this, you can use the custom init (let's assume you have 2 controllers `VC1.swift` and `VC2.swift`):

`VC1.swift`

```
import UIKit

class VC1: UIViewController {
    // your buttons
    @IBOutlet var greenButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var redButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func makeThemGreen(sender: AnyObject) {
        // How you call your new view
        let vc2view = VC2(color: vc2Style.Green)
        self.presentViewController(vc2view, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func makeThemRed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc2view = VC2(color: vc2Style.Red)
        self.presentViewController(vc2view, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

`VC2.swift`

```
import UIKit

// you create an enum to propose different style for your buttons or other components
enum vc2Style: Int {
    case Green
    case Red
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var btnA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnC: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // convenience init for making custom init
    convenience init(color: vc2Style) {
        self.init()
        // check the style which has been "ordered" and display your components with custom style!
        switch(color) {
        case .Green:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        case .Red:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }      
}
```

So basically, you will create custom init for your second view and will call them from your first view while touching the buttons.